# My small std::unique example not working

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to use `cxx-11`'s `std::unique()` to find 
the unique elements in an `array`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>


int main(){
    const int n=11;
    double x[n],a3[n],a1[n];

    x[0]=-0.717778;
    x[1]=-0.496843;
    x[2]=-0.429063;
    x[3]=-0.3596;
    x[4]=-0.205607;
    x[5]=0.0730536;
    x[6]=0.138018;
    x[7]=0.585526;
    x[8]=2.40104;
    x[9]=3.75268;
    x[10]=4.55704;

    a3[0]=0.790832;
    a3[1]=0.569896;
    a3[2]=0.502116;
    a3[3]=0.432653;
    a3[4]=0.343625;
    a3[5]=0.512472;
    a3[6]=0.56708;
    a3[7]=1.01459;
    a3[8]=2.32799;
    a3[9]=3.67962;
    a3[10]=4.48398;

    std::cout.precision(10);
    std::copy(a3,a3+n,a1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)            a1[i]+=x[i];            
    std::sort(a1,a1+n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)            std::cout << a1[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    int n_1=std::unique(a1,a1+n)-a1;
    std::cout << "length of unique subvector " << n_1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n_1;i++)         std::cout << a1[i] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "---" << std::endl;    
}
```

but when I'm running this [code (link to coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f951c92de052dbf)
 it returns:

```
original array
0.073053
0.073053
0.073053
0.073054
0.138018
0.5855256
0.705098
1.600116
4.72903
7.4323
9.04102
---
length of unique subarray 10
---
unique array
0.073053
0.073053
0.073054
0.138018
0.5855256
0.705098
1.600116
4.72903
7.4323
9.04102
---
```

the unique array still contains a duplicate (and so is wrong)!

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: another floating point value comparison problem....

Comment: floating point arithmetic with `std::unique` ?

Comment: What you are doing is expecting double representation to be precise... which it's not (esp. after the calculation..)

Comment: [no duplicates if you have enough precision](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e6070260f58172d)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try with a bit more precision, `std::cout.precision(20)`:

```
0.073052999999999979064
0.073053000000000034575
0.073053999999999952308
0.13801800000000000179
0.58552559999999997942
0.70509800000000000253
1.6001160000000000938
4.7290299999999998448
7.4322999999999996845
9.0410199999999996123
```

Since most decimal fractions can't be represented exactly by a binary floating point format, slightly different rounding errors cause slightly different results.

In general, you can't expect the results of different floating point calculations to be exactly equal, even if the corresponding calculations applied to mathematical real numbers would be.

You could instead test for "almost equality", carefully choosing a tolerance that's appropriate for your numerical domain. `unique` allows you to specify your own predicate, instead of a simple equality test:

```
std::unique(a1,a1+n,[](double x, double y){return std::abs(x-y) < tolerance;});
```

Comment: thanks, but I get: 'main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:42:77: error: ‘tolerance’ is not captured'  (I have added  const double tolerance=1e-16;' to the code) and was wondering if you knew more...

Comment: @user189035: If it's a local variable, then the lambda needs to capture it. Replace `[]` with `[=]` or `[tolerance]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
int n_1 = std::unique(a1,a1+n,
            [](float a, float b)
            {
                return std::fabs(a-b) < 10e-9;
            }
          ) - a1;
```

?

[Live demo link](http://ideone.com/M9ETrd)